# In R, looking for a more detailed str() showing full names or a tree

Tags: r

I want to change parts of a `ggplot2` object made by a function and returned as a result, to remove the Y-axis label. No, the function does not allow that to be specified in the first place so I want to change it after the fact.

```
str(theObject) ## shows the nested structure with parts shortened to ".." and I want to be able to type something like:

theObject$A$B$C$myLabel <- ""
```

So how can I either make an `str` -like listing with full paths like that or perhaps draw a tree structure showing the inner working of the object?

Yes, I can figure things out using `names(theObject)` and finding which branch leads to what I am looking for, then switching to that branch and repeating but it looks like there could be a better automated way to find a leaf node such as:

```
leaf_str(obj=theObject, leaf="myLabel")
```

might return zero or more lines like:

```
theObject$A$B$C$myLabel

theObject$A$X$Y$Z$myLabel
```

Or, the entire structure could be put out as a series of such lines.

I have searched and found nothing quite like this. I can see lots of uses especially in teaching what an object is. Yes, S4 objects might also use @ as well as $.

Comment: Just do `theObject + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())`. There is no need to muck about with the object's internals.

Comment: If you want to study and change the internals, you can use the second parameter of `str` to control the depth of nesting and call `str` on the relevant subsets. `leaf_str(obj=theObject, leaf="myLabel")` can't work because there can be several `myLabel` objects in the structure.

Comment: Exploring objects in R is super easy. First do `str(x)`, then do `str(x$A)` and slowly climb down the tree to where you want to be.

Comment: Roland, I like your answer and oddly I found the same solution of "adding" of using a function to blank it earlier. But I still wanted a way to access and change random objects especially since many do not have functions that easily do things. Also, if you develop an object and want to write such functions, then you may need to internally address deep components. I also did explore the options for using str and know how to do what you said and many things you did not. None automate the process togenerate a good search or overall view. XML has path operations analogous to what I am looking for.

Comment: Roman, I agree you can do it manually step by step and said so in my original. But we may disagree on what is super easy. In brief, I want something that gets the names of an object and for each name, concatenates that with a recursive call using that sub-object. This recurses as needed and you return a vector or list of all possible paths. You can then use the result to make a graph or search for leaf nodes, meaning something that ends with $ then the name, and so on. str throws away lots of such info by using .. and not indenting right. As noted, I have seen such functionality elsewhere.

Comment: It would be easy enough to write such a function ... It might even exist in some package. Personally, I don't really need it. PS: Use @username to ping commenters.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
tree
```

function in the xfun package may be useful.

See here for more details

https://yihui.org/xfun/